# Store: how to configure promotions in bulk?

Tags: expresso-store

I'm about to launch several EE sites with Expresso Store. Each site will basically have the same products. And when some of the products go on promotion, they need to happen across the individual sites.

Is there a way to quickly replicate the configuration of promotions (e.g. a 50% discount sale on 100 products) across multiple sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `exp_store_discounts` table in the database. You could write once query which inserts a new discount and run it on each database as required.

The only hitch would be if it were applied to specific categories or entry IDs, those may vary from site-to-site.

Comment: I had a quick look at that table. Presumably I only need to make a single entry in `exp_store_discounts` if I were doing a single promotion? And a single entry in `exp_store_sales` if I were doing a sale? No complex relationships I need to be away of? I understand the issue about entry IDs, but each of my products have a unique product code that I can use.

Comment: Correct on both counts - these tables are pretty straight forward.